# error clearing an object of non-trivial type with memset

Tags: c++, g++, memset

Well, the thing is simple, im getting
`warning: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘struct FormatHashBuffers(CBlock*, char*, char*, char*)::<unnamed>’; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess] memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));` on this function and idk why, when i build with g++ 5 no warning, but when i build with 7.1 or 8.5 i  get the warning, any idea why or how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
    void FormatHashBuffers(CBlock* pblock, char* pmidstate, char* pdata,
                       char* phash1) {
    //
    // Pre-build hash buffers
    //
    struct
    {
        struct unnamed2
        {
            int nVersion;
            uint256 hashPrevBlock;
            uint256 hashMerkleRoot;
            unsigned int nTime;
            unsigned int nBits;
            unsigned int nNonce;
        }
        block;
        unsigned char pchPadding0[64];
        uint256 hash1;
        unsigned char pchPadding1[64];
    }
    tmp;
    memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));

    tmp.block.nVersion = pblock->nVersion;
    tmp.block.hashPrevBlock = pblock->hashPrevBlock;
    tmp.block.hashMerkleRoot = pblock->hashMerkleRoot;
    tmp.block.nTime = pblock->nTime;
    tmp.block.nBits = pblock->nBits;
    tmp.block.nNonce = pblock->nNonce;

    FormatHashBlocks(&tmp.block, sizeof(tmp.block));
    FormatHashBlocks(&tmp.hash1, sizeof(tmp.hash1));

    // Byte swap all the input buffer
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(tmp) / 4; i++)
        ((unsigned int*)&tmp)[i] = ByteReverse(((unsigned int*)&tmp)[i]);

    // Precalc the first half of the first hash, which stays constant
    SHA256Transform(pmidstate, &tmp.block, pSHA256InitState);

    memcpy(pdata, &tmp.block, 128);
    memcpy(phash1, &tmp.hash1, 64);
}
```

Comment: Why not initialize the member variables in your class instead?

Comment: The warning was added at some time between version 5 and version 7.1. (Developers have a limited amount of time to add warnings for special cases.) You solve the problem by not using `memset` in a way that has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could default-initialize your member variables:

```
struct {
    struct unnamed2 {
        int nVersion{};
        uint256 hashPrevBlock{};
        uint256 hashMerkleRoot{};
        unsigned int nTime{};
        unsigned int nBits{};
        unsigned int nNonce{};
    } block;

    unsigned char pchPadding0[64]{};
    uint256 hash1{};
    unsigned char pchPadding1[64]{};
} tmp;
```

With that there's no need for `memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));` and the warning will go away.

Comment: Im compileing, if no warn, i aprove your answere. Thanks man!

Comment: Well, you cannot assume that the usage of memset is purely a thing for initialization. It might also be the case that you need to use memset if you purely want to reset the data - a case where i would say that a quick and dirty memset is still valid.

Comment: @Tobibobi I'd say the cases are few where I'd prefer a `memset` to that of assigning a default initialized object to the target. I'd be surprised if `tmp = decltype(tmp){};` produced any less efficient code than `memset` and it would _always_ be valid for types that _can_ be default initialized. It's also future proof. If the default initialization is changed to something else, writing `0` straight into the memory, a `memset` would cause hard to find bugs, while `tmp = decltype(tmp){};` would still do the right thing.

Comment: But why that code generated a warning?  All data members of the struct are of primitive data types.

Comment: @shargors  We haven't seen what definition of the `uint256` type OP used and unfortunately, the account seems to have been closed since the question was asked.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would imagine it would be something primitive, something like using uint256 = unsigned int8_t[32].  Assuming that uint256 is derived using another primitive data type, why compiler generate a warning?

Comment: @shargors I would need to see that hypothetical definition to be able to answer that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would imagine it would be something like this:
uint256 = unsigned int8_t[32];

Comment: @shargors Well, that _is_ a trivial type so if that was the definition it would indeed be surprising if the compiler said that it was not a trivial type.

Answer (score 4):

To initialize struct variable you can use

```
tmp = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force the memset so be accepted by the compiler by casting the destination to a void pointer:

```
memset((void *)&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
```

Beware of any potential side effects when members are not primitive types.

Comment: It works with `memset(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&tmp), 0, sizeof(tmp));` also

Answer (score 0):

> any idea why

Obviously, the -Werror flag was not set properly for your g++ v5 environment or it was not considered by the developers at that time. It should always produce this warning.

> how to solve it?

Simply not refer to memset here! Since possible performance issues can be neglected here due to the presence of SHA256Transform() at least in contrast, you should prefer a clean explicit initialization here instead. Try to avoid the nested struct (since the inner is already been used within a more "global" scope anyways further on) and refer to aggregate/uniform initialization or an explicit factory way.

Comment: and where i should refer to memset? please helpme explaining a bit more how i should fix this and i accept your answere.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo was faster than me :) See his answer.